# How to resize Partitions on Proxmox?

Tags: linux, lvm, partition, proxmox

Hey im Hosting Proxmox on a Small Hosting Provider and after i added more Space to my "sda" Proxmox refused to start and i wasnt able to go on the WebInterface.
I still was able to go into NoVNC to look at the Screen of the VM And when i wanted to apt update it it said there was no space left on the device. So i run lsblk and sure enough pve-root was full and my new 100GB of space lied unused on "sda" with a bit of googling i was able to put the new 100GB on "sda3" but now i have to give pve-root a few bites of spaces and the rest of it to my lvm-thin pool or where the vms have the files.

[Output of "lsblk"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui40S.png)

Comment: Please do not link or paste pictures of text you can copy and plaste as text.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enlarged the physical volume, next you must enlarge the logical volume and the filesystem

```
lvresize --size +100G --resizefs /dev/xxxx/...
lvresize --extents +100%FREE --resizefs /dev/xxxx/...
```

And end you must enlarged your the filesystem

```
resize2fs /dev/sdaX
```

Comment: Hey, i tried out the first Command but it gives me the Following Error:
`/etc/lvm/archive/.lvm_panel_33679_245062869: fclose failed: No space left on device`

Comment: hmm okay, can remove some files and try again?